# Import error: No module named qgis.core

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I am trying to install QGIS 2.16 (Nodebo) on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but as soon as I start the application I get the following error:

`Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named qgis.core

Python version:
2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

QGIS version:
2.16.2 'Nødebo', 979e1a2

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/matt/.qgis2/python', u'/home/matt/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg']

I've already tried to set the PYTHONPATH variable (to /usr/share/qgis/python) and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (to /usr/lib/ -> this is where libqgis_core.so.2.16.2 is located. Is this path wrong?)

maybe my anaconda2 makes the trouble but how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the anaconda2 path from my PATH variable and now it works. I wrote a script which sets the PATH variable (remove the anaconda2 path) and starts QGis.

If someone knows a better solution, please let me know!